# Codeigniter 3 url route with independent controllers

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, controller, routes, codeigniter-3

I have created a web application with Codeigniter, and I have a problem at the url, controller and structure level.

I have the following web structure.

```
http://projectroot/admin
```

Then I have several sections like:

```
http://projectroot/admin/users
http://projectroot/admin/profile
http://projectroot/admin/section_tracking
http://projectroot/admin/section_products
etc...
```

I'm working with sessions and other libraries

Currently I have everything in a single controller called Admin, but I would like to create independent controllers that would be calling each part of the url.

In Admin I have:

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller {
   public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->library('form_validation');
      $this->load->library('My_PHPMailer');
      $this->load->library('session');
   }
   public function index(){
      if($this->session->userdata('login')){
         if($this->session->userdata('urlnow')){
            $url = $this->session->userdata('urlnow');
            redirect($url);
         }else{
           redirect('admin/index');
         }
      }else{
         $data = array();
         $data['usererror'] = $this->session->flashdata('usererror');
         $data['passerror'] = $this->session->flashdata('passerror');
         $data['message'] = $this->session->flashdata('message');
         $this->load->view('admin/index', $data);
      }
   }
...
public function users() {
code....
}
public function profile() {
code....
}
public function section_tracking() {
code....
}
public function section_products() {
code....
}
```

My idea is that the controller folder contains something like this:

```
admin.php
users.php
profile.php
section_products.php
section_visits.php
```

Creating independent Admin extends classes  (user, profile, section_tracking and section_products) as independent controllers outside of admin, with a structure similar to this:

```
users.php
class Users extends Admin {
public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->library('form_validation');
      $this->load->library('My_PHPMailer');
      $this->load->library('session');
   }
   public function index(){
   code here...
  }
}

profile.php
class Profile extends Admin {
public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->library('form_validation');
      $this->load->library('My_PHPMailer');
      $this->load->library('session');
   }
   public function index(){
   code here...
  }
}
```

How can I do it? I don't want to use HMVC, I just want with MVC native.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your application/controllers/admin folder...Make following files

```
Admin.php
Users.php
Profile.php
Section_products.php
Section_visits.php
```

Then make call to each files like this...

```
http://projectroot/admin/users
http://projectroot/admin/profile
http://projectroot/admin/section_tracking
http://projectroot/admin/section_products
etc...
```

And here you want to extends `admin` controller.so make `Admin_controller.php` by extending `CI_Controller` in `application/core`. Your `Admin' controller must be like this....

```
class Admin_controller extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Then always extends `Admin_controller`.`CI_Controller` automatically extended.

Comment: I can access profile only if I put:
http://projectroot/profile

But I want it to work like this:
http://projectroot/admin/profile

In route I have:
$route['default_controller'] = 'admin';
$route['admin'] = "admin";
$route['(:any)'] = 'admin/$1';

Comment: Great, Thanks so much, I could solve it, it was necessary to configure the file routes.php, I just put this way:
$route['(:any)'] = 'admin/$1';

Comment: congrats and enjoy with codeigniter. If answer is useful please accept it and vote up.thank you.